# How to display circle coordinates and borders in a video

Tags: python, image, opencv, video, jupyter-notebook

I want to detect only the billiard balls inside the square, but circles in other places are also detected.
And the coordinates are not displayed as x and y, but 3 values, and the coordinates of the circle I want to take coordinates on do not come out well because the billiard ball is not recognized properly.

```
### file association
file = "C:\\Users\\woo\\Documents\\billiards_in.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)

### video output
while True:
    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k == ord("q"): break

### Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret: break

### Billiard Table Display - Rectangle
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (250, 100), (1250, 600), (0, 255, 255), 2)

    if ret:
        # image processing
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(0,0),1)
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(frame, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,50,
                              param1= 150, param2= 40, minRadius= 1, maxRadius= 100)
        circle = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

        for cx,cy,radius in circles[0,:]:
            ### circle sign
            cv2.circle(frame,(cx,cy),int(radius),(0,255,255),2)
            ### ball coordinate display
            cv2.putText(frame,str(circles),(cx,cy),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.75,(255,0,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

    else:
        print("Can't receive frame. Exiting...")
        break

    ### frame output
    cv2.imshow("VideoFrame", frame)

### When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Do you know what's wrong with my code??
(+ I want to upload the mp4 file used in the code, but I don't know how to upload it..)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: please add a picture. those usually help.